# Get the height of SafeAreaView from within BottomTabBar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am attempting to use [`react-native-keyboard-spacer`](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) in conjunction with [`react-navigation`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation).

I am currently setting the `topSpacing` of the keyboard spacer to be `-49` which is the height of the tab bar from `react-navigation`, but the tab bar is within a [`SafeAreaView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview) which *magically* adds padding to move content into an area that doesn't interfere with native UI.

This means that when viewing the app on an iPhone X, or other similar devices, the tab bar becomes taller than `50`.

What would be the best way to get the height of the `SafeAreaView`?

Comment: Hey, Can you upload code along with a screenshot of your problem? that might help to understand your problem well and I suggest to use keyboardAcoidingView and SafeAreaView to avoid your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Another option with `react-native-safe-area-context` (https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context):

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
...
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
```

Then you can get the bottom safe area height from `safeAreaInsets.bottom`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the list padding from `react-navigation` SafeAreaView

### LandScape Mode

```
paddingLeft: 44
paddingRight: 44
paddingBottom: 24
paddingTop: 0
```

### Portrait Mode

```
paddingLeft: 0
paddingRight: 0
paddingBottom:34
paddingTop:44  // ... Including Status bar height
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [react-native-safe-area](https://github.com/miyabi/react-native-safe-area). it provides function to Get safe area inset top, bottom, left, right.

```
import SafeArea, { type SafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area'

//Retrieve safe area insets for root view

SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView()
.then((result) => {
   console.log(result)
   // { safeAreaInsets: { top: 44, left: 0, bottom: 34, right: 0 } }
})
```

Comment: @IanArko I am not sure please check once. In recent projects, I have used the react-native-safe-area-context' along with react-navigation. It provides similar API please check this link for more details https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context

Answer (score -1):

Below is not supported anymore, for update check here https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context

[npm install react-native-safe-area-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view)

```
import { getInset } from 'react-native-safe-area-view';
const bottomPadding = getInset('bottom', false); //2nd param islandscape
//outputs bottom safe area height
```

Comment: The new version of this package has removed `getInset` function.

Comment: getInset is unavailable on react-native-safe-area-view